# Django - Blank together in model fields

Tags: django, django-models

How to do something like this:

```
class Example(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    alt_name = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        blank_together = ('name', 'alt_name') #?!
```

EDIT: This is similar to `unique_together`. When a field is filled, the user has to fill both.

Comment: It would help if you described exactly what you want that to do.

Comment: You mean to say, you want to mark multiple fields as blank using Meta class ?

Answer (score 2):

Below is an implementation of a `mixin` that accomplishes this.

```
# your_app/mixins.py

class BlankAble(models.Model):
    # when creating the BlankAble class object it will add a __blank_together__ 
    # attribute corresponding to the same in {YourModel}.MyMeta.blank_together
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        new = super().__new__(cls)
        if hasattr(cls, 'MyMeta'):
            if hasattr(cls.MyMeta, 'blank_together'):
                setattr(new, '__blank_together__', cls.MyMeta.blank_together)
        return new


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # returns False if any but not all of the __blank_together__ fields 
        # are not blank
        blank_together = not (any([getattr(self, field, None) for field in getattr(self, '__blank_together__', None)]) and \
                              not all([getattr(self, field, None) for field in getattr(self, '__blank_together__', None)]))
        if not blank_together:
            raise ValidationError(f"{getattr(self, '__blank_together__', None)} must all be blank together.")
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)


    class Meta:
        # prevents Django from having some bad behavior surrounding
        # inheritance of models that are not explicitly abstract
        abstract = True

# your_app/models.py    

class TestModel(BlankAble, models.Model):

    test_field1 = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=25)
    test_field2 = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=25)
    test_field3 = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=25)

    class MyMeta:
        blank_together = ('test_field1', 'test_field2')
```

If you are interested in learning more about `mixins` I highly recommend Two Scoops of Django's take on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

You can try, save method;

```
   def save(self,*args, **kwargs):
      if self.name == '' or self.alt_name == '':
         self.name = ''
         self.alt_name = ''
      super(Example, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually I am using this tip. But I have to use this many times in my code. So I want to do that like `unique_together` for easier to use.